# How do you disconnect Facebook accounts from Instagram?

Tags: facebook, instagram, facebook-account, instagram-account

I signed up for Instagram and it said I already had an account with that email address. I didn't remember signing up but thought maybe I had done it a while ago. I reset my password and logged in.

It turned out someone else had signed up using my Gmail address. They had like 2 or 3 pictures posted. I wasn't really sure what to do since it was my email address they used (its a @gmail.com - I get a decent amount of email for people with my name).

The problem is that they linked their Facebook account to Instagram. I also linked my Facebook account. I get notifications of "my" Facebook friends joining Instagram but it's this other person's Facebook account. In the Instagram app, it only shows my Facebook as a linked account. How can I get this other Facebook account detached from my Instagram account?

Comment: As per my knowledge, you can add only one Facebook account with Instagram until you are not using any third party tool. Can you please attach a screenshot how it is showing two linked account and how it is not giving option to unlink?

Answer (score -1):

unlink your FB account from Instagram

1. Go to Instagram settings.
2. Click on linked accounts.
3. Unlink the facebook.

Answer (score -2):

Try this, you need to remove Instagram from login with Facebook in the apps section.

1. Go to Account Settings > Apps >Logged in with Facebook
2. Scroll down to Instagram and remove it.

Comment: The problem is that the problem account is a Facebook account that I have no control over, it's someone else's Facebook account.

Answer (score -5):

Go to your iPhone setting>safari>delete browser history.

Comment: How is that going to help?